# Ubuntu 18.0.4 wifi does not work after power off / reboot

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, reboot, realtek-wireless

I used the following procedure

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new/
git checkout origin/extended -b extended
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

However when my system powered-off and rebooted the wifi does not work anymore.

I cannot run the above one more time since already rtlwifi_new directory is present and the above procedure errors with the following:

sudo modprobe rtl8723de
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723de': Exec format error

How can I fix this issue ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
cd ~/rtlwifi_new
make clean
cd
sudo apt install dkms
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Reboot

You are likely seeing the Exec Format error because you are not doing a `make clean` and it is building for an older kernel

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. You are right after I did make clean, the Exec format error did not come.

Comment: I have a question to you. Why when powered off, this wifi adapter installation is going away ? Did I miss anything in my previous step.

Comment: In terminal, run long command `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`  Post URL